# Presta - display SKU under products name on any page

Tags: html, css, prestashop

Can you show me how to display SKU under products name on any page?
I tried to copy this part of code from product.tpl but it shows nothing :(

On product page (product.tpl) I use:

```
{if $product->online_only}
            <p class="online_only">{l s='Online only'}</p>
        {/if}
        <div class="clearfix product-header-cust">
            <h1 itemprop="name" style="float: left;">{$product->name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}</h1>
            <p id="reduction_percent" style="float: left;" {if !$product->specificPrice || $product->specificPrice.reduction_type != 'percentage'} style="display:none;"{/if}>
                <span id="reduction_percent_display" class="reduction_percent_display_cust">
                    {if $product->specificPrice && $product->specificPrice.reduction_type == 'percentage'}-{$product->specificPrice.reduction*100}%{/if}
                </span>
            </p>
        </div>  
        <p id="product_reference"{if empty($product->reference) || !$product->reference}"{/if}>
            <label>{l s='Model'} </label>
            <span class="editable undertitle" itemprop="sku">{if !isset($groups)}{$product->reference|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}{/if}</span>
        </p>
```

And i tried to copy this part:

```
<p id="product_reference"{if empty($product->reference) || !$product->reference}"{/if}>
            <label>{l s='Model'} </label>
            <span class="editable undertitle" itemprop="sku">{if !isset($groups)}{$product->reference|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}{/if}</span>
        </p>
```

Under this (product_list.tpl):

```
<h5 itemprop="name" class="product-list-name">
                        {if isset($product.pack_quantity) && $product.pack_quantity}{$product.pack_quantity|intval|cat:' x '}{/if}
                        <a class="product-name" href="{$product.link|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" title="{$product.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" itemprop="url" >
                            {$product.name|truncate:45:'...'|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}
                        </a>    
                    </h5>
```

So it looks like:

```
    <h5 itemprop="name" class="product-list-name">
                        {if isset($product.pack_quantity) && $product.pack_quantity}{$product.pack_quantity|intval|cat:' x '}{/if}
                        <a class="product-name" href="{$product.link|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" title="{$product.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" itemprop="url" >
                            {$product.name|truncate:45:'...'|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}
                        </a>    
                    </h5>
 <p id="product_reference"{if empty($product->reference) || !$product->reference}"{/if}>
            <label>{l s='Model'} </label>
            <span class="editable undertitle" itemprop="sku">{if !isset($groups)}{$product->reference|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}{/if}</span>
        </p>
```

But it shows nothing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :
`{if isset($product.reference) && $product.reference}
    <p id="product_reference">
            <label>{l s='Model'} </label>
            <span class="editable undertitle" itemprop="sku">   {$product.reference|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}</span>
        </p>
{/if}`

Regards,